# Problem when loading images with AJAX

Tags: javascript, image, jquery

I'm using a jquery plugin to load images from flickr. I'm trying to distribute these images into 3 columns as they come in, the goal being to place each image in the shortest column so that the columns are close to equal length at the end.

The script works great most of the time in IE. It was less dependable in Firefox but seems better now. In Chrome however it totally fails. I have narrowed the problem down to the fact that while the script is running it thinks the images have zero dimensions. The dimensions don't appear until some later point, but I want to distribute the images as they come in, not do a big reshuffle at the end. Why does occur even when I use the Image object? And how can I get around this problem?

Comment: a bit of relevant code would be very useful! can you show us the part you've narrowed it down to? or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks guys. I did have to resort to firing the distribution function from the onload of each image. Which means the images have to be hidden when they first load. I thought I would have to scrap the flickr plugin I was using but I managed to integrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myimg = document.getElementById('myimage');
```

if I give this dude a new source, the img.onload event will fire, so I need to put the code that should fire after load in the onload event handler.

```
myimg.onload = function(){
    //do some crap
}
myimg.src = someAjaxCall();
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should try to get the image dimantion with the load() event

```
$('img').load( function() {
   alert( $(this).width() );
});
```

Comment: Great answer, as it uses jQuery. My answer doesn't use jQuery, but still a great answer also.